# Is GObject used much outside of GNOME?

Tags: gtk, gobject

I understand GObject started out as part of gtk+ and was later separated from the GUI related elements. What I would like to know is: it used outside gtk+ ? what about other desktop environments, and other OSs like Windows or Mac OS? Are there any prominent examples of such cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some things here and there that use GObject without GTK+, but AFAIK they are few and far between.

I'm guessing that the most prominent ones right now are [Clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org/)-based projects (it's a graphics-oriented UI library). There are also a small number of projects based on [libgnt](http://developer.pidgin.im/doxygen/dev3.0.0/html/group__gnt.html) (text-based UI library), and possibly various non-GTK+ programs written in [Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala) (a C#-like programming language with GObject-based classes).

Edit: Also [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) (thanks liberforce!), which is a popular multimedia library. The vast majority of GStreamer projects also use GTK+, but I'm sure there are some non-GTK+ ones.